# Perl one-liner for replacing values greater than a threshhold

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have a text file which contains 7 columns of floating point values (). I would like to use perl one-liner and find the values which are greater than a threshold in the `7th` column. Then, I want to replace the values of `4th`, `5th`, `6th`, `7th` in the rows whose `7th` column's value exceed the threshold with `0.00000000`. Could someone please let me know how I can do that?

Here is an example. Let's assume the threshold is 1.00000.

```
  0.04718683      0.24081557      0.02831210      0.98316791      0.00000000     -0.98446111      1.39132413
  0.05662420      0.24081557      0.02831210     -0.00006975      0.00001697     -0.00144172      0.00144350
  0.06606157      0.24081557      0.02831210      0.00039672      0.00007192     -0.00001264      0.00040339
  0.07549894      0.24081557      0.02831210      0.00087559      0.00010765     -0.00028455      0.00092694
  0.08493630      0.24081557      0.02831210      0.00004609      0.00012754     -0.00030319      0.00033214
  0.09437367      0.24081557      0.02831210     -0.00038816      0.00008384      0.00011519      0.00041348
```

In the first line, column `7th` has a value greater than threshold, `1.39132413 > 1.00`. Therefore, the first line needs to be replaced with the following (zero values) and all other lines remain intact as they don't meet the criteria.

```
  0.04718683      0.24081557      0.02831210      0.00000000      0.00000000     0.00000000   0.00000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to keep the whitespace exactly the same, this works:

```
$ perl -lane 'do{$_=sprintf("%.8f",0) for @F[3..6]} if $F[6]>1; print "@F"' file 
0.04718683 0.24081557 0.02831210 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 
0.05662420 0.24081557 0.02831210 -0.00006975 0.00001697 -0.00144172 0.00144350
0.06606157 0.24081557 0.02831210 0.00039672 0.00007192 -0.00001264 0.00040339
0.07549894 0.24081557 0.02831210 0.00087559 0.00010765 -0.00028455 0.00092694
0.08493630 0.24081557 0.02831210 0.00004609 0.00012754 -0.00030319 0.00033214
0.09437367 0.24081557 0.02831210 -0.00038816 0.00008384 0.00011519 0.00041348
```

To skip a certain number of lines, just test for the value of `$.` (the current line number):

```
$ perl -lane 'do{$_=sprintf("%.8f",0) for @F[3..6]} if $F[6]>1 && $.>3; print "@F"' file
```

Comment: Thanks. Whitespaces are not important for me. Is is also possible to skip the first three lines in the text file and then perform this operation?

Comment: @A2009 sure, just add `&& $. >3` before the `print` call. See update.

Comment: +1. An even more elegant way to do the zeroing: `map {$_=sprintf ".8f",0} @F[3..6]`